# drush sql-sync: "The external command could not be executed due to an application error."

Tags: 8, database, drush, ssh

When I execute `drush sql-sync @production @local -d` to get a database from the server to local, I get the following error after login with ssh:

```
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.
```

Here is the debug after the ssh login:

```
Backend invoke: php
C:/Users/x/drupal-root/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --backend=2 --verbose --debug --uri=mysite.localhost --root=/C/Users/x/drupal-root/web  sql-conf --all 2>&1
php C:/Users/x/drupal-root/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --backend=2 --verbose --debug --uri=mysite.localhost --root=/C/Users/x/drupal-root/web  sql-conf --all 2>&1
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.
Error: no database record could be found for target @local
Returned from hook drush_sqlsync_sql_sync_validate
Command dispatch complete
```

Drupal version: 8.2.7

Drush version: 8.1.8

This is my local alias:

```
$aliases['local'] = array(
    'uri' => 'mysite.localhost',
    'root' => '/C/Users/x/drupal-root/web',
    'path-aliases' => array(
      '%drush' => '/C/Users/x/drupal-root/vendor/drush/drush',
      '%dump-dir' => '/C/Users/x/.drush',
      '%files' => '/C/Users/x/drupal-root/web/sites/default/files',
     ), 
  );
```

Here is the output of `drush @local status`:

```
PHP configuration      :  C:\x\xampp\php\php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush script           :  C:/Users/x/drupal-root/vendor/drush/drush/dr
                           ush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1.8
 Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp
 Drush configuration    :  C:\Users\x\.drush\drushrc.php
 Drush alias files      :  C:/Users/x/.drush/example.aliases.drushrc.php
```

Does anyone have an idea? I'm at my wits' end.

Comment: I see that the returned error is "no database record could be found for target @local". I would investigate that. To get better help, tell us what version of Drush (and Drupal), the exact command you ran, maybe the output of drush status (local and remote) and so on.

Comment: Ok, I added more details

Comment: Thx. Since the error is "no database record could be found for target @local", I would investigate if the local alias works - does the "status" command report sensible info for the database, are you able to connect use the "sql-cli" command and so on.

Comment: When I type `drush status` the normal database infos are shown, with `drush sql-cli` an empty command line opens where nothing happens, whatever I type and enter...

Comment: It's `drush @local status` and so on you should test. (Yeah, sql-cli might not be a test candidate on Windows.)

Comment: Ok, I added the output. I wonder why it shows the example.aliases file - My correct alias file is in drupal-root/drush.
When using sql-sync it seems to use the correct file:
`Loaded alias @local from file C:\Users\x\drupal-root\web/../drush/mysite.aliases.drushrc.php`

Comment: Maybe because you didn't running Drush from inside your Drupal root? Anyway, my point is that you can't expect sql-sync to work if the local alias doesn't work for commands on your local Drupal installation.

Comment: Yes, I did ;). Also `drush sql-dump` is working perfectly... May it has to do with the URI?